# When window popup is opened web pages not switch tabs. No other page can be opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popupwindow

When window popup opened no other page of the web application can be switched. 
When I close Popup window everything works fine.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal for browsers. You are trying to print something, so browser blocked any other actions. There is no issue with your website.

Comment: okay, but is there any way if user minimize popup and want to proceed to website.

Comment: @danish443, i dont think so